# Get all results from Case statement on to one row

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I'm trying to get results from multiple months into one row:

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       year, 
       period, 
       CASE 
         WHEN sub_period = 'S1' THEN Sum(credits) 
         ELSE 0 
       END Tot_S1_Cred, 
       CASE 
         WHEN sub_period = 'S2' THEN Sum(credits) 
         ELSE 0 
       END Tot_S2_Cred, 
       CASE 
         WHEN sub_period NOT IN ( 'S1', 'S2' ) THEN Sum(credits) 
         ELSE 0 
       END Tot_Other_Cred 
FROM   student 
WHERE  period = '201750' 
       AND status IN ( 'RE', 'RW' ) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          NAME, 
          year, 
          period, 
          sub_period
```

Currently, I'm getting a row for each valid case statement:

```
|ID    | NAME    |YEAR   |PERIOD   |S1_CRED   |S2     |Other
|---   |----     |-------|------   |-------   |------ |------
|1     |Abbott   |2017   |201750   |0         |3      | 0
|1     |Abbott   |2017   |201750   |0         |0      |0
|2     |Costello |2017   |201750   |0         |3      |0
|3     |Popeye   |2017   |201750   |3         |0      |0
|3     |Popeye   |2017   |201750   |0         |6      |0
|3     |Popeye   |2017   |201750   |0         |0      |9
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: That's a case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: But what result you want? Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a conditional `SUM`, so put the `CASE` inside the `SUM()`

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       year, 
       period, 
       SUM ( CASE WHEN sub_period = 'S1' 
                  THEN credits
                  ELSE 0 
             END
           ) as Tot_S1_Cred, 
       SUM ( CASE WHEN sub_period = 'S2' 
                  THEN credits
                  ELSE 0 
             END
           ) as Tot_S2_Cred, 
       SUM ( CASE WHEN sub_period NOT IN ('S1', 'S2')
                  THEN credits
                  ELSE 0 
             END
           ) as Tot_Other_Cred,   
FROM   student 
WHERE  period = '201750' 
       AND status IN ( 'RE', 'RW' ) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          NAME, 
          year, 
          period
```

Comment: also remove  `sub_period` from `group by` clause

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I tried putting the CASE inside the sum and am still receiving a row each time there's a value in the case expression. My goal is one line per person and a sum of credits or 0 for each sub period.

Comment: again, show us sample data and expected output. Otherwise this is a guessing game. But @DmitryGrekov has a point remove `sub_period` from `group by` clause

Comment: remember accept one answer if your problem is solve using the green tick.

Comment: It was a combination of the two answers:

1. Conditional Sum: I moved the CASE expression inside the Sum
2. I then removed the sub_period from the group by clause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to user the same case:

```
select Id
      ,name
      ,year
      ,Period
      ,case
         when Sub_Period in ('S1', 'S2')  then
          sum(Credits)
         else
          sum(Credits)
       end Tot_S1_Cred
  from Student
 where Period = '201750'
   and Status in ('RE', 'RW')
 group by Id
         ,name
         ,year
         ,Period
         ,Sub_Period
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your case statments with :

```
   Case When sub_period = 'S1'                       Then 'Tot_S1_Cred'
        When sub_period = 'S2'                       Then 'Tot_S2_Cred'
        When sub_period NOT IN ( 'S1', 'S2' )        Then 'Tot_Other_Cred'
        Else 'NA' End   As 'Credit Type'

   ,Sum(credits) As 'Amount'
```

Full Query:

```
SELECT id, 
       NAME, 
       year, 
       period, 
       Case When sub_period = 'S1'                  Then 'Tot_S1_Cred'
            When sub_period = 'S2'                  Then 'Tot_S2_Cred'
            When sub_period NOT IN ( 'S1', 'S2' )   Then 'Tot_Other_Cred'
            Else 'NA' End   As 'Credit Type'
        ,SUM(credits)

FROM   student 
WHERE  period = '201750' 
       AND status IN ( 'RE', 'RW' ) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          NAME, 
          year, 
          period,
```